# GXT3 - ColumnSelectionAppearance ClassCastException

Tags: java, gxt

I have trouble implementing the GridSelectionModel (using CheckBoxSelectionModel as an inspiration).
I'd like to create a RadioSelectionModel but I have a ClassCastException when I call my constructor.
Here's my class structure (If needed I put some code but I don't think that's necessary). I'm using list and sublist to show the classes and embedded classes :

- `class RadioSelectionModel < M > extends GridSelectionModel< M >`

  - `interface RadioColumnAppearance < M >`
- `class RadioColumnDefaultAppearance < M >`

  - `interface RadioColumnStyle extends CssResource, ColumnHeaderStyles, GridDataTableStyles`
  - `interface RadioColumnResources extends ClientBundle`

The `RadioColumnAppearance` is link to `RadioColumnDefaultAppearance` by a gwt.xml file with :

```
<replace-with
    class="com.app.appearance.RadioColumnDefaultAppearance">
    <when-type-is
        class="com.app.grid.RadioSelectionModel.RadioColumnAppearance" />
</replace-with>
```

I happened to found that the `ClassCastException` is when I call `GWT.create( RadioColumnAppearance.class )` but I don't know what is exactly 
 the problem and how I can solve it

EDIT : Here's the RadioColumnDefaultAppearance code. I believe that the problem is in here because I only have the exception when I call GWT.create. About the error, it's a simple message I get in my browser console `Uncaught java.lang.ClassCastException` :

```
public class RadioColumnDefaultAppearance < M > implements CheckBoxColumnAppearance< M >
{

public interface RadioColumnStyle extends CheckBoxColumnStyle
{

}

public interface RadioColumnResources extends ClientBundle
{
    @Source( "/css/RadioColumn.css" )
    RadioColumnStyle style();

    @Source( "column.png" )
    @ImageOptions( repeatStyle = RepeatStyle.Vertical )
    ImageResource specialColumn();

    @Source( "column_checked.png" )
    @ImageOptions( repeatStyle = RepeatStyle.Vertical )
    ImageResource specialColumnSelected();
}

private final RadioColumnResources resources;
private final RadioColumnStyle style;

public RadioColumnDefaultAppearance()
{

    this( GWT.< RadioColumnResources > create( RadioColumnResources.class ) );
}

public RadioColumnDefaultAppearance( RadioColumnResources resources )
{
    this.resources = resources;

    this.style = this.resources.style();

    StyleInjectorHelper.ensureInjected( style, true );
}

public void renderRadio( Context context, M value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb )
{
    sb.appendHtmlConstant( "<div class='x-grid-row-checker'>&#160;</div>" );
}


}
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact stack trace? Or some code? Or both?

Comment: I've edited the message, hope that help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RadioColumnDefaultAppearance does not implement the RadioColumnAppearance interface. If you want to define a default implementation for an interface, the class must implements that interface otherwise it would not possible to assign an instance of the implementation class to an interface reference.

Comment: The interface and the class are in two differents project. The link between them is made with the gwt.xml

Comment: The link just tell gwt which class to instanciate when you call GWT.create(RadioColumnAppearance.class) but because the linked class does not implement the RadioColumnAppearance you receive a ClassCastException

Comment: You were right but now I have another error while compiling : `Errors in 'jar:file:RadioColumnDefaultAppearance.java'
Failed to resolve RadioColumnDefaultAppearance.RadioColumnResources' via deferred binding
Scanning for additional dependencies: jar:file:ColumnHeader.java
For the following type(s), generated source was never committed (did you forget to call commit()?)
RadioColumnDefaultAppearance_RadioColumnResources_de_InlineClientBundleGenerator`

Comment: This looks like some source code is missing from your gwt compile path, probably ColumnHeader. Make sure that you have all the sources from the external libraries you are using.